# Eclipse Code Template to automatically generate trim()-call on String setter-method parameters

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

does anyone know how to tell Eclipse to generate setter methods for Strings which call trim() on the parameter before it is assigned?

Answer (score 1):

An ugly(!) way to do it is write the following in Workspace -> Preferences -> Java ->Code Style ->Code Templates -> Code -> Setter Body -> Edit

```
if (${param} instanceof String)
{
    ${field} = ${param}.trim();
}
else 
{
    ${field} = ${param};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. it is ugly indeed ;) I think I'd rather use a String converter for JSF or a special Hibernate String UserType.